# sql server or c# code modify column then update all the columns that follow

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, .net-core

how to use sql cte or c# code to complete Modify the middle row amount then update all the balance that follow,this is customer bill table every time you add a record, you need to display the latest balance, Balance += previous row Balance ,How to achieve high performance code because of a lot of data

```
  Id      Amount   Balance
  1         1         1
  2         2         3
  3         3         6
  4         4         10
  10000     10000     10010
  。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。
```

Comment: You shouldn't compute values from previous rows and store, risk of data inconsistency. I'd create a view instead, that always will be up to date. (Or perhaps a _computed column_ would do fine too.)

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using ?

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: this is  customer bill table  every time you add a record, you need to display the latest balance.

Comment: Hint: `SUM() OVER()`

Comment: Wouldn't you need to consider payments as well to work out a true balance? I agree with @Jarlh though, this information almost certainly belongs in a view.

Comment: @jarlh The correct way to design this table

Comment: @GarethD According to my needs, how can I design the best?

Comment: @Sami Thank you for your answer and solved my problem.

Comment: linq  how to code SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY Id)

Comment: @Squirrel The balance is just a view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Sami hint, you can use SUM() in a query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6cd25/4)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerBill
(
  Id INT,
  Amount  INT
);
INSERT INTO CustomerBill (Id, Amount)
VALUES (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (10000, 10000)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *, SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS Balance
FROM CustomerBill
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6cd25/4/0)**:

```
|    Id | Amount | Balance |
|-------|--------|---------|
|     1 |      1 |       1 |
|     2 |      2 |       3 |
|     3 |      3 |       6 |
|     4 |      4 |      10 |
| 10000 |  10000 |   10010 |
```